# Using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync to deserialiaze into object with factory in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have got a question I got a DTO object with a private contructor and create factory method, a very easy example:

```
public class Text
{
    public string Value { get; }

    private Text(string text)
    {
        Value = text;
    }

    public static Result<Text> Create(string text)
    {
        const int minLength = 10;
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return Result.Failure<Text>(DomainErrors.TextIsNullOrEmpty);
        }

        return new Text(text);
    }
}
```

So I am receiving this object throu rest api and was trying to deserialize it using:

```
var companies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ImmutableArray<Text>>(stream, _options);
```

But of course as there is no public contructor for this object JsonSerializer throws an exception that he needs one. So as I am not allowed for changing this can this can be deserialized in any way?

Comment: custom JsonConverter ... ?

Comment: What behavior are you after? Do you want this to be unconditionally deserialized, even if the `Value` is invalid, or to actually run the validation in `Create` on deserialization?

Comment: I assume that Text will always be valid so this is unnecessary from my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I deserialize Json with private constructor using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147552/can-i-deserialize-json-with-private-constructor-using-system-text-json)

Comment: You could deserialize into collection of dynamic/expandoObjects and then call Text.Create(string text) method over them to populate ImmutableArray<Text>